Progress bar reset the progress
I want to make a progress bar which loads to 100% in x seconds and whatever is the progress to be able to reset it via js.
I am using bootstrap and @keyframes to animate the bar:


//reset the progress every 5 seconds.
setInterval(() => {

    let progressBar = document.getElementById("myProgressBar");

    progressBar.classList.remove("load");
    progressBar.classList.add("load");

    console.log("reset");

}, 5_000);
@keyframes load {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.progress-bar.load {
  animation-name: load;
  animation-duration: 60s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="progress" style="height: 15px;">
      <span class="progress-bar load" id="myProgressBar">
    </span>
  </body>
</html>



And in js I try to reset the progress:
progressBar.classList.remove("load");
progressBar.classList.add("load");

But the progress is not reset.

@mplungjan , i updated it.

Removing and re-adding the class happens "uninterrupted" here, the JS engine is still in control when this happens, and only afterwards control is passed back to the rendering engine - so the latter does not notice, that any change actually happened here. For workarounds - see duplicate.

@CBroe , that works. Thank you.
